# Add GeoJSON properties to each marker in an android map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, geojson, markers

i'm using a geojson file which has a lot of features like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Number": "233",
            "Name": "233_SAN_JUAN_BOSCO_SANTIAGO_RUSIÑOL",
            "Address": "San Juan Bosco - Santiago Rusiñol"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -0.369528093405798,
                39.497128187401
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Number": "211",
            "Name": "211_CALLE_FRAY_JUNÍPERO_SERRA_ESQ_CALLE_VALL_D'UIX",
            "Address": "Fray Junípero Serra - Vall d'Uixó"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -0.397848157697943,
                39.45869404863428
            ]
        }
    },
```

So, I added this info to a layer in maps, and all the markers appear correctly placed, but they have no title or snippet. I used this code:

```
 GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.valencia, this);

        GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle = new GeoJsonPointStyle();

        layer.addLayerToMap();

       for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {  //loop through features

           pointStyle.setTitle(feature.getProperty("Number"));
           feature.setPointStyle(pointStyle);
       }
```

So, as you can see, I tried to make a loop through all the features to add the correspondent Title(Number) to each marker.

**The problem is that**, instead of getting an individual title, all features get the same title. In addition, this title changes everytime I run the app.

Any idea of how to modify the loop so this works?

Comment: Try creating a new `GeoJsonPointStyle` for each `feature` moving this line `GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle = new GeoJsonPointStyle();` inside the `for` loop

Comment: Oh god, that did the trick! :D Thank you very much!